# How to change text in widget using c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have widget `dialogBottom` with element `Text` and I need to change it's text in c++. As I understand, if I use `meta` word, then I can write the name of widget and access it's variables by creating variables with the same name in code. But by some reason variable `Name` is always null

.h

```
UCLASS()
class HOME_API AAct_31 : public AActor
{
  GENERATED_BODY()

  UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (dialogBottom))
  class UTextBlock* Name = nullptr;

  virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
};
```

.cpp

```
void AAct_31::BeginPlay()
{
  Super::BeginPlay();
  
  if (Name)
  {
    char* t1 = "text1";
    FText t2 = FText::FromString(ANSI_TO_TCHAR(t1));
    Name->SetText(t2);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to change the text of a text block widget within a widget in C++, then you need to make a class of type `UUserWidget` and parent your widget blueprint with this class. And then in this class, you can call `GetWidgetFromName` to get specific widgets like so,

```
// assuming that the native construct is overridden in the header file
void UCustomWidget::NativeConstruct() {
    Super::NativeConstruct();

    // assuming that RandomTextBlock is defined in the header file and is of type UTextBlock*
    RandomTextBlock = (UTextBlock*)GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name_Of_TextBlock"));
    RandomTextBlock->SetText(FText::FromString("Random String"));
}
```